# Database storage limit for open source PostgresSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-size, hardware

I just started using PostgresSQL.  When I installed SQL Server Express years back, you typically had a database storage limit if you didn't install the full version.  I think I remember it being 4GB, but that might have changed.  Is there a database storage size limit for PostgresSQL without buying additional licenses or hardware?  What is that limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On their webpage [About](http://www.postgresql.org/about/) they clarify that the limit is a lot huge than 4GB.

Limit        Value

Maximum      Database Size  Unlimited

Maximum      Table Size 32 TB

Maximum      Row Size   1.6 TB

Maximum      Field Size 1 GB

Maximum      Rows per Table Unlimited

Maximum      Columns per Table  250 - 1600 depending on column types

Maximum      Indexes per Table  Unlimited